# Can't get facebook ID

Tags: facebook

I can't create an app for my FB page, when I try to access http://developers.facebook.com/apps/ I get redirected to my page. Does anyone else have a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using Facebook as your Page and not you.

Select the option use Facebook as you from your page and then you should be able to visit http://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and create an App. Shortcut link http://developers.facebook.com/setup/

Once created you can add said app to your page (still using Facebook as you and not your Page).

Comment: I did make a facebook page at first, now I tried to use it as a user. When I click on the apps link i get redirected to my own page. Thanks for the answer anyway